# Get ID selected item in backend list sitefinity

Tags: backend, sitefinity

I want get selected item in backend list sitefinity to export [as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwzXl.png). Can anyone help me how to do that.

Comment: is this Export button a custom one that you have added? If so, how did you add it, is it via extending the adminApp project?

Comment: Yes, I used sitefinity admin app extension

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far?

Comment: https://github.com/duythuong97/sitefinity-button-export.git. I have built this extension and add to sitefinity project. You can see the code in the commands-extender folder